# android - Corrected text in EditText not received

Tags: android

I have two date fields (no, not the pickers) as `fromDate` and `toDate`. When I click on my `Submit` button, in the `onResume()`, I have validations in place for both date fields. When I enter an invalid value (not from syntax, locale, etc. point of view) for `toDate` and click `Submit`, I correctly see the toast. Then, I enter the correct the value and click `Submit`. The toast still appears ! In other words, the corrected date value is not being received.

I guess, I am missing the activity life-cycle w.r.t. toasts. (Each `Toast` is immediately followed by a `return`.) Can you please suggest what should be the correct flow to handle this error followed by correction ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Locale l ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set locale;
        l = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        addButtonListener();        
    }

    private void addButtonListener() {
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            EditText fromDateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fromDate);
            EditText toDateText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.toDate);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s;
                if (fromDateText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.err_fromDate_1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (toDateText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.err_toDate_1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edited to add source code.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/MUh2fgyq

Answer (score 0):

Make fromDateText and toDateText class variables and init them in onCreate.

Comment: O.k. just curious, how does it solve the problem? Isn't the activity in resumed status during editing, correction, etc?